# Hub reference does not find in asp.net core signalR 1.1.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr-hub

I am using Asp.net Core 2.2 framework, and i have installed asp.net core signalR 1.1.0 version.
When I create hub class , then hub reference does not find ?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;

namespace signalRCoreClientJS.Hub
{
    public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
        {
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That is not the only thing that makes signalr work

Comment: Michael, I did not got your point?

Comment: That code is not all that is required to get signalr working, where is the rest of the setup code